# Unexpected namespace prefix “app” found while trying to use my custom Layout

Tags: android, view

I write a custom ViewGroup, and define two properties for this custom ViewGroup's child to use, like ConstraintLayout's `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf`, my property is `stayLeft`.

When i use `stayLeft` property, the project can run normally. But the IDE always prompt me ： Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag TextView less...

> MyViewGroup

```
class MyViewGroup @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ViewGroup(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun generateLayoutParams(attrs: AttributeSet?): MyLayoutParams {
        return MyLayoutParams(context, attrs)
    }

    override fun checkLayoutParams(p: LayoutParams?): Boolean {
        return p is MyLayoutParams
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
        // TODO("not implemented")
    }

    class MyLayoutParams(context: Context, attrs:AttributeSet?) : ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(context, attrs) {

        private var stayLeft : Int = 0
        private var stayRight : Int = 0

        init {
            val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.MyViewGroup_Layout
            )

            stayLeft = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyViewGroup_Layout_stayLeft, 0)
            stayRight = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyViewGroup_Layout_stayRight, 0)

            a.recycle()
        }

    }
}
```

> attrs.xml

```xml
    <declare-styleable name="MyViewGroup_Layout">
        <attr name="stayLeft" format="reference" />
        <attr name="stayRight" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

> activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.aprz.myapplication.MyViewGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            app:stayRight="@id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.aprz.myapplication.MyViewGroup>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

error tips on this line:

```xml
app:stayRight="@id/tv1"
```

This looks like the IDE can not recognise my custom property. What should i do to eliminate the error tips??? And why ConstraintLayout do not have this error??? I do not want to suppress this lint error.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to opening tag of layout in your xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

For example, If your app package was com.li.myapp ,
your layout would now look like this:

```
<com.aprz.myapplication.MyViewGroup
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                app:stayRight="@id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </com.aprz.myapplication.MyViewGroup>
```

As for why it doesn't show your error in ConstraintLayout, you didn't post full code here so I can only make guesses. It could be that in ConstraintLayout, this property has some other name than "app".

**Edit** : I just noticed that your stylable name is different than your class. Try renaming your styleable name same as your class name like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyViewGroup">
    <attr name="stayLeft" format="reference" />
    <attr name="stayRight" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: activity_main.xml already added opening tag. I post my activity_main.xml again.

Comment: If i rename my styleable name as you say, IDE warn me  this :  ```By convention, the declare-styleable (MyViewGroup) for a layout parameter class (MyLayoutParams) is expected to be the surrounding class (MyViewGroup) plus "_Layout", e.g. MyViewGroup_Layout. (Various editor features rely on this convention. ``` And this does not work.